# GraphDB won't use all available memory

Tags: sparql, rdf, graphdb

**I'm running a "big" `SAPRQL INSERT WHERE` on GraphDB and it doesn't seem to be using all of available physical RAM.**

I'm using a 64GB, 4-core CentOS 6.9 server

```
-bash-4.1$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         64428      21897      42530          0        107       2877
-/+ buffers/cache:      18912      45515
Swap:         8095          0       8095
```

I started GraphDB 8.3.0 like this:

```
graphdb -Xms50g -Xmx50g -d
```

It's a non-inference repo, if that makes any difference

Here's what the sysinfo page says

*application info:*

```
OS: Linux 2.6.32-696.6.3.el6.x86_64
Java: Oracle Corporation 1.8.0_144
Memory used: 5554 MB
Max memory: 50977 MB
```

*JVM arguments*

```
-Xms1g
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:HeapDumpPath=/usr/local/graphdb/heapdump.hprof
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p
-Dgraphdb.dist=/usr/local/graphdb
-Xms50g
-Xmx50g
```

top output:

```
top - 13:32:23 up 22:37,  1 user,  load average: 1.00, 0.96, 0.76
Tasks: 153 total,   1 running, 152 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 25.1%us,  0.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 74.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  65974292k total, 22390544k used, 43583748k free,   109900k buffers
Swap:  8290300k total,        0k used,  8290300k free,  2915740k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 4071 sprqlusr  20   0 56.2g  17g  22m S 101.0 28.4  16:53.29 /usr/local/java/bin/java -Xms1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:+HeapDumpO
```

And here's a screenshot of the memory utilzation page

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you are forcing the JVM to use 50g heap size instead of letting it allocate available memory as needed? I am not saying what you are doing is wrong, just asking. What happens to the memory profile if you just run `graphdb -d`?

Comment: @Nathan ... good question.  next time I take the db offline I'll try that.  I guess it was a sloppy attempt to see IF GraphDB can use all of the allocated RAM.  I've never seen the graphdb process use more than ~30% of the RAM, so it's been bothering me, and I thought this stuck query would be a good case.

Answer (score 2):

By default, GraphDB will allocate 50% of the available heap for its global page cache, the structure responsible for caching all disk pages and minimizing the I/O time. The value is controlled in conf/graphdb.properties by a line starting with graphdb.page.cache.size. In your scenario, the global cache is set by default to 25GB.

As a rule of thumb, you can calculate that a repository with 1 billion RDF statements will take around 100GB disk space if all indexes are switched on. From the heap memory usage diagram, it looks like that your dataset is just not big enough to fill the cache size.

For setups using fast SSD disks, it makes very little difference to allocate more cache size bigger than 15-30% of the total repository size. Setting a bigger heap size may even hurt the repo's performance because of the longer GC cycles. I highly encourage you to limit your maximum heap size to less than 32GB to benefit from the `-XX:+UseCompressedOops`, which should be nearly equivalent to the 50GB heap size without the pointer compression. This behavior is consistent with other Java applications managing [big heaps sizes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html#compressed_oops).

Comment: Thanks. Just getting around to working through your suggestions. **I don't see a graphdb.properties file in either of my systems**: Windows 10, GraphDB 8.4.1 from easy installer (I searched the whole disk) OR CentOS 6.9, GraphDB 8.3.0, standalone server (I searched my "data" folder that contains subfodlers `refine`, `repoPenaltyBox`, and `repositories`, as well as `/usr/local/graphdb-free-8.3.0/`, which contains `bin`, `conf`, etc.)

Comment: I downloaded the dist package (*.zip) and the file is located inside at `/conf` - not sure how this works for `deb`, `rpm` etc

Comment: @MarkMiller The fastest way to locate GraphDB's /conf path when installed as a native application on the various platforms is to click the GraphDB's icon on the task bar and press "Show logs directory". Then browser one directory up.